# Chirpy, 10-year-old-girl vocalization on the media

Tags: phonology

I am 81 and have embraced vocal fry as the new modern speech. But now
I hear a lot of females on the media who sound like ten-year-old
girls, ---or the sound-track of a cartoon chipmunk. Chirpy.

What's up with this? Where can I read about this curious phenomenon?

Thanks!

Richard Gross

Comment: You might be interested in this Language Log post: ["Sexy baby vocal virus"](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=5842)

Comment: It's probably related to Valleyspeak. Young males have a version of this as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found these two:

- A scientific article: http://www.jvoice.org/article/S0892-1997(11)00070-1/abstract .
- A TV News article: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEqVgtLQ7qM&feature=youtu.be